# Responsive DIVs overlaying on "background-size: contain" - solve the issue where the alert fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

### Problem:

I am using a `background-size: contain` image with DIVs overlaying on top, and I want them to stay stationary relative to the scale and aspect ratio of the image.

It works, but for a small issue wherein the browser's width is less than the background image's. When this happens, you can see the overlay DIVs (**.navbar** and **#home**, respectively) begin to slide out of place, only to immediately snap back to their correct positions once the browser corrects itself.

I've written up a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3vj9mt1/1/) that contains an alert. The alert fires when the browser width is less than the background image width. You will need to resize your browser window horizontally to get it to trigger. You can comment out the alert to observe the DIV shifting.

What is causing this, and how can I prevent it?

### Code:

```
var width = $('.bg').width();
var height = $('.bg').height();

var imgWidth = width > height ? 350/325 * height : width;
var imgHeight = height > width ? 325/350 * width : height;
var imgTop = imgHeight * .75 + ((height - imgHeight) / 2);

$('.navbar').css({
    'width': imgWidth,
    'height': imgHeight * .15,
    'top': imgTop + 'px'
});

$(window).on("resize", function() {

    width = $('.bg').width();
    height = $('.bg').height();

    imgWidth = width > height ? 350/325 * height : width;
    imgHeight = height > width ? 325/350 * width : height;
    imgTop = imgHeight * .75 + ((height - imgHeight) / 2);

    if (width < imgWidth) {
        //alert(width + 'x' + height + ', ' + imgWidth + 'x' + imgHeight);
    }

    $('.navbar').css({
        'width': imgWidth,
        'height': imgHeight * .15,
        'top': imgTop + 'px'
    });

});
```

Comment: Not very clear what the issue is and what problem you want to solve...

Comment: It's difficult to describe; you have to see it yourself. Make your browser smaller (horizontally) until the alert fires. Then comment out the alert and, at that same spot, watch what happens to the red and green boxes. They shift downward briefly, then snap back up if you keep zooming in. I want them to not shift downward. I want them to stay positioned perfectly across all resizes of the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It jumps because:

You have a rectangular image--350px X 325px.  So this means `width === 350px` and `height === 325px`.

You are checking whether `width > height` and `height > width` in these two lines:

```
imgWidth = width > height ? 350/325 * height : width;
imgHeight = height > width ? 325/350 * width : height;
```

i.e. You are checking whether the width (which starts out at 350px) is greater than height (325), and whether height (325) is greater than width (350).

Taking the second example:  The height will not be greater than the width until after you've shrunk the window horizontally 25px (350 - 325) beyond the point where the image starts to shrink.  And so, for those first 25px, the height isn't recalculated because `height > width` is still false.

The easiest remedy for this is simply to check against the offset--check whether `width - 25 > height` and whether `height + 25 > width`:

```
imgWidth = width - 25 > height ? 350/325 * height : width;
imgHeight = height + 25 > width ? 325/350 * width : height;
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3vj9mt1/3/)

Also, for what I think is cleaner code, though a more complex fix, check out this fiddle [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3vj9mt1/4/)

Comment: I think you're on the right track with offsets, but they are not working as intended. In your first Fiddle, if you apply the same logic to a larger image, the DIV shift is much more pronounced. In the second Fiddle, the DIVs shift wildly when you resize vertically.

Comment: What about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jcu48azL/1/ -- It seems to work properly for all resizes, except there is a very brief blip where it pixels shifts WILDLY. Perhaps it's a rounding calculation problem?

Comment: Never mind. Just make it: ``if (width <= imgWidth)`` and it works. While I didn't end up using any offsets nor finding them necessary, you got my gears turning. Thanks for the helpful answer! Giving it to you.

Comment: Why thank you!  Sorry I did not do extensive bug-checking.  Glad I could help.